# Что такое интерфейс в C#?

Tags: c#

Что такое интерфейс в C# и с чем его едят. Если можно, на русском. ))

Я вот так понимаю. Значит, если класс должен по-любому реализовать методы интерфейса, то получается, все классы, что наследуют интерфейс, должны реализовать его методы?

Answer (score 9):

Интерфейс - это в каком-то смысле договор. В случае, если вы наследуете интерфейс, вы заключаете договор, по которому обязаны реализовать все методы этого интерфейса в своем классе. Если ваш класс не реализует какой-то метод, значит, он автоматически является абстрактным классом, и вы по нему не имеете права создавать объект, но можете этот класс наследовать в другом классе и реализовать метод уже в нем.

Если ваш абстрактный класс уже реализовал какой-то метод интерфейса, то потомкам этого абстрактного класса эти методы реализовывать не обязательно.

Интерфейсы часто используются в различных библиотеках, где методы ждут определенный объект, который в обязательном порядке должен реализовать метод от какого-то интерфейса.

Comment: Я вот просто представил все это дело в ООП. Предположим строим систему "Машина" Есть класс "руль" и класс "колесо". Как я понимаю чтобы эти классы взаимодействовали друг с другом они должны реализовать интерфейс "рулевое".??????
))

Answer (score 0):

[Здесь](http://soft-develop.com.ua/development-csharp-oop/841-interfaces) и [здесь](http://www.volgota.com/yaroslavz/c-25-interfeysy) есть хорошие статьи по этому поводу.

К вашему вопросу. Все методы в интерфейсе являются абстрактными, и любой класс (не абстрактный, спасибо gympi), наследующий тот или иной интерфейс, обязан реализовывать все его методы.

Comment: Просто есть маленькая тонкость, Если класс не реализует все методы интерфейса он может существовать, но не может быть создан объект по этому классу, это халевар но тонкость важная, когда будут создаваться собственные библиотеки этот момент будет использоваться часто.