# Generic Типы и UpCast к базовому интерфейсному типу(ковариантность обобщений)

Tags: c#, generics

Всем привет, имеется следующий код:

```
public abstract class Shape { }
public class Circle : Shape { }

public interface IContainer<T>
{
    T Figure { get; set; }
}

public class Container<T> : IContainer<T>
{
    public T Figure { get; set; }

    public Container(T figure)
    {
        this.Figure = figure;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Circle circle = new Circle();

        IContainer<Circle> container = new Container<Circle>(circle);

        Console.WriteLine(container.Figure.ToString());

        // Delay.
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Итак, вкратце  -  что я понял в данном примере.

В данном примере мы сперва создаем абстрактный класс с именем Shape{}, затем мы создаем конкретный класс с именем Circle - который наследуется от абстрактного класса shape.

далее мы создаем открытый интерфейс с именем IContainer - параметризированный  -                                      указателем места заполнения типом Т ,  и в теле данного интерфейса, мы создаем абстрактное авто-свойство с именем Figure  - типа указателя места заполнения типа Т.

Далее vss создаем класс с именем Container - который реализует интерфейс IContainer, который в свою очередь(интерфейс) параметризирован типом места заполнения типом Т.

В теле класса Container мы реализуем абстрактное свойство Figure, и после этого мы создаем конструктор, который принимает один аргумент типа указателя места заполнения типом Т, и в теле этого конструктора мы авто свойству Figure присваиваем значение аргумента данного конструктора нашему свойству.

Далее, в классе Program, в теле метода Main(), мы создаем экземпляр класса Circle - который как мы помним наследуется от абстрактного класса Shape.

На строке:

```
IContainer<Circle> container = new Container<Circle>(circle);
```

- мы создаем переменную с именем container - типа базового интерфейсного типа IContainer, а параметр типа места заполнения типом Т у этого базового интерфейсного типа мы "закрываем" нашим типом Circle.

Условно разделим приведенную ниже строку на две части:

*IContainer<Circle> container* = **new Container<Circle>(circle);**

(курсив - первая часть , жирная - вторая часть)

- **в итоге** мы ожидаем создаваемый во второй части строки - экземпляр класса Container - ожидаем привести его к базовому интерфейсному типу Icontainer, но в самом созданном экземпляре будет хранится свойство того типа, которым мы "закрываем" место заполнения типом Т при создании данного экземпляра - а т.к в данном случае мы "закрыли" при создании экземпляра типом Circle, то в данном случае внутри данного экземпляра будет храниться свойство Figure типа Circle(а точнее реализация этого свойства из конкретного класса Container наследуемого от интерфейса IContainer)

**Вот мой вопрос:** с абстрактным классом Shape{} и конкретным классом Circle{} - наследующим его  - все понятно.

Затем, кто-нибудь объясните толком и по человечески что такое интерфейс и для чего он нужен (нет, я конечно его изучал, но толком не понял; вот например про делегаты мне простым языком объяснили так  - "Делегаты — это способ сделать следующее: взять произвольный кусок кода, упаковать его в объект (экземпляр делегата) и вызвать этот кусок кода в любом месте, куда получится передать ссылку на наш экземпляр делегата." - может это и не совсем правильно, но это понятно!)

С авто свойством, его реализацией и конструктором - ине тоже все понятно.

также не понятно зачем автор курса говорит: "но в самом созданном экземпляре будет хранится свойство" - с какого перепугу? Т.е как я *догоадываюсь(но не понимаю навернякка)* - в экземпляре хранится то, что переданно в него конструктором(в нашем случае пользовательским) - а т.к аргумент конструктора через ключнвое слово this принимает значение метода set, то косвинно  (чере конструктор) мы как бы принимаем в экземпляр значение свойства.

И **мой самый главный вопрос** также вытекает из "что такое интерфейсы - толком" - непонятно зачем мы передаем конструктору уже готовый экземпляр класса Circle, - т.е неужели мы его(этот экземпляр передаваемый как аргумент конструктора) приводим к типу этого интерфейса.

напоследок вот картинка, на которой я пытался разобраться в ситуации:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Конкретно в данном случае можно спокойно писать код и без интерфейса. Интерфейсы нужны, чтобы закрыть потребность в множественном наследовании, которое в c# недоступно, но бывает в реальном мире (и доступно в C++ к примеру).

Comment: как вопрос в заголовке связан с вопросами в тексте?

Comment: Ответ на вопрос в его текущем виде потянет на пару глав хорошей книги. Книгу можно выбрать тут http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/416584/198316. Постарайтесь конкретизировать вопрос или разделите его на несколько. И крайне желательно, чтобы заголовок вопроса соответствовал его содержанию.

Comment: Интерфейс: [(1)](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/20620/10105), [(2)](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/235352/10105), upcast: [(3)](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/433314/10105).

Answer (score 2):

1. Интерфейс - это контракт, обязательство класса иметь некоторые методы/свойства, описанные в нем. Грубо говоря это чертеж скелета.
2. Абстрактный класс — это тело, но без руки. Функционировать не может, но понятно, что надо добавить.
3. Generic Inerface - это тот же интерфейс (обязательство класса). Различие с обычным интерфейсом в том, что не декларирован материал, из чего тело делать. Оно представлено как Т - некий тип (в аналогии материал).

Итак, переводя рассуждение в плоскость скрина.
*Conteiner<T>* - обобщенный тип. Что именно туда засовывать, решаем сами в коде.
В main можно видеть что тип определили как Circle, так что Clr создает у себя отдельный тип *Conteiner<Circle>*, уже не обобщенный, как мы видим и с ним идет работа.

Так же, если ниже ты определишь *Container<Object>*, *Container<Point>* - то на каждый такой "вызов" будет создан свой тип. Это легко проверить. Объяви внутри обобщенного класса *static* поле и поиграйся с ним, ты увидишь, что в случае разных типов вместо обобщенного *Т* у тебя будут разные значения в статичных полях.