# Что такое Interface в C#?

Tags: c#, интерфейс

Изучаю C#. Никак не могу понять смысл интерфейсов. Примеры, которые приводятся на тех или иных ресурсах не дают мне полного понимания смысла интерфейсов. 
Что я понял:

- В интерфейсах объявляются методы и свойства(как и в обычном классе)
- Если класс наследуется от интерфейса, он обязан реализовать все методы интерфейса
- Интерфейсы желательно начинать с буквы I - IComparable (желательно, но не обязательно)

НО, остается непонятной вещь - мне все равно надо реализовывать все методы, которые я наследую, что не ведет к уменьшению количества кода, а даже наоборот. Пример взятый из интернета

```
public interface IPizza
{
    public void Order();
}

public class PepperoniPizza : IPizza
{
    public void Order()
    {
        //Order Pepperoni pizza
    }
}

public class HawaiiPizza : IPizza
{
    public void Order()
    {
        //Order HawaiiPizza
    }
}
```

Если смотреть от обратного, то я не просто создаю методы в каждом классе, но еще и объявляю непонятный интерфейс и наследую от него свои классы, что только увеличило мой код... Код аккуратно вставить не получилось... Прошу помочь разобраться.

Comment: Вы можете объявить метод с параметром IPizza и передавать ему экземпляр любой пиццы. Без интерфейса этого не сделать. И при этом ваш метод будет уверен, что у любой полученной пиццы есть метод Order

Comment: связанный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/398007/213987

Comment: Вы можете заказать много пицц, все их поместить в массив типа IPizza, и в цикле пройтись по массиву и вызвать метод Order.

Comment: Хм... Допустим в представлении клиент выбирает три пиццы. Метод контроллера public ActionResult GetOrder(List<IPizza> Pizzas){ foreach(var pizza in Pizzas){pizza.Order()} return View();} Так будет выглядеть?

Comment: связанный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/20620/186999

Comment: Интерфейсы и не обязаны помогать сокращать код, они помогают его структурировать. Если у вас маленькая изолированная система состоящая из одного класса, то добавление интерфейса только бесполезно увеличит объем кода.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Воспринимайте интерфейс, как контракт на реализацию определённых методов в несвязанных классах.

Грубо говоря, наследуя класс от интерфейса вы обязуетесь реализовать в этом классе определённые методы, при этом сами классы могут иметь совершенно различную "родословную".

В итоге, в любом методе, где вы получите экземпляр класса реализующего интерфейс, вы сможете вызвать нужный вам метод не заботясь о том, что за класс вам прислали.

Например, у вас есть система, которая отвечает за то, чтобы давать пинка каждому, кто проходит мимо. Чтобы не реализовывать в этой системе кучу ифов с проверкой на классы, чтобы понять каким образом пинок должен влиять на этот объект (лёгкий - подбрасывать, тяжёлый - толкать и т.д.) - вы создаёте интерфейс `IPushable`, который говорит, что реализующий его класс имеет метод `PushIt(float velocity)`. А всю логику по применению ускорения от пинка передаёте в сами классы, которые реализуют этот интерфейс.

Сама же система получает вошедший объект через какой-нибудь метод вроде 
`public void ObjectIn(object obj)`. В этом методе делает проверку `if (obj is IPushable)` и если она истина - то со всей своею первобытной яростью даёт объекту пинка, через приведение типов

```
var pushable = obj as IPushable;
pushable.PushIt(velocity);
```

Таким образом вы сможете пинать хоть коробку, хоть слона, хоть птицу Говорун, отличающуюся умом и сообразительностью. При этом все эти сущности между собой никак не связаны, а пинающая система понятия не имеет кого она там пнула.